What's the correct tag question for "You found nothing"?
What's the correct tag question for the "You found nothing" statement?

You found nothing, did you?

or

You found nothing, didn't you?

?

Either is correct, depending on the intent of the questioner. 'Did you?' if they already know (or have heard) that nothing was found, and wish to discuss that fact, and 'didn't you?' if they are not sure that nothing was found and wish to confirm.

This is straightforward, so I'm guessing the confusion comes from the fact that "nothing" is a negative idea. Although "You found nothing" and "You didn't find anything" have the same meaning, all that matters for tag questions is the version that negates the verb. You can't say "You didn't find anything, didn't you," only "... did you."
With positive verbs you can use either, and finding "nothing" is functionally no different than finding "something."
